# Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSEntityDescription *' with an expression of type '__kindof NSManagedObject * _Nonnull'

Tags: xcode, core-data, nsentitydescription

every thing works fine but i get this notice

and try to search to find solution but with no luck

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
NSManagedObjectContext *context = appDelegate.managedObjectContext ;
NSString *title = [[Picker delegate]pickerView:Picker titleForRow:[Picker selectedRowInComponent:1] forComponent:1];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"History" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

The method you're calling returns an instance of `NSManagedObject`. You are assigning it to a variable of type `NSEntityDescription`. That's what the message is telling you.

Comment: So how to declare the NsEntityDescription

Comment: You can look it up in the `NSManagedObjectModel`, but this is rarely necessary or useful. What are you trying to do here? It looks like you want to create a new instance of the entity. If so then you're doing everything right *except* using the wrong variable type on that line. The line creates an `NSManagedObject`, which is what it looks like you want.